# Node.js - combine default export with non default exports

Tags: javascript, node.js

How do you translate this code:

```
import a from "./a"

export default a;
export { default as b } from "./b";
```

To node.js using classic syntax?

```
// This is what I have tried
module.exports = {
   ...require("./a"),
   b: require("./b),
}
```

---

```
import a, { b } from "index";

const a, { b } = require("index");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just:

```js
module.exports = require("./a");
module.exports.b = require("./b);
```

Be careful that the order of the exports is important: default comes first.

Or, if you prefer:

```js
module.exports = Object.assign(require("./a"), {
    b: require("./b")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use default and non-default like this :

```
    export default function  A(){}
    export function B(){}
    export function C(){}
´´´

To import use :
```

```
import A, {B,C} from "...path from component";
... your code
```

´´´

Hope help you ;)

Answer (score 0):

To use with require you'll need a bit more. If you can use `import/export` it'll be better.

If you compile this code with TypeScript, this is the generated output

`/index.ts`

Input

```
import a from "./a";

export default a;
export { default as b } from "./b";
```

Output

```
"use strict";
var __createBinding = (this && this.__createBinding) || (Object.create ? (function(o, m, k, k2) {
    if (k2 === undefined) k2 = k;
    Object.defineProperty(o, k2, { enumerable: true, get: function() { return m[k]; } });
}) : (function(o, m, k, k2) {
    if (k2 === undefined) k2 = k;
    o[k2] = m[k];
}));
exports.__esModule = true;
exports.b = void 0;
var a_1 = require("./a");
console.log("a", a_1["default"]);
exports["default"] = a_1["default"];
var b_1 = require("./b");
__createBinding(exports, b_1, "default", "b");
```

`/test.ts`

Input

```
import a, { b } from ".";

console.log("a", a);
console.log("b", b);
```

Output

```
"use strict";
exports.__esModule = true;
var _1 = require(".");
console.log("a", _1["default"]);
console.log("b", _1.b);
```